# Is it possible to change the jquery validation message to each element field of a collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The idea is to return an error message to each field, changing the original requied message of jquery. The way I'm doing it, returns: "The true field is required."

```
function addRequired() {        
    var container, inputs, index, input;

    // Get the container element
    container = $('#entityFields');

   // Find its child `input` elements
   inputs = container.find('input').not("#EntityWebsite, #EntitySocialMoney");

   for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
       input = inputs[index];
       input.required = true;
       $.validator.messages.required(input.labels[0].innerText);
   }  
}  

$.validator.messages.required = function (label) {
   var requiredMessage = "The " + label + " field is required."
   return requiredMessage ;
}
```

My html is something like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
 <div id="seriesTab" class="tab-pane">
   <div id="entityFields" class="form-row">
        <label>Entity</label>
        <input type="text" columnDivClass="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Address:</label>
        <input type="text" columnDivClass="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" columnDivClass="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" columnDivClass="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Website:</label>
        <input type="text" columnDivClass="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>SocialMoney:</label>
        <input type="text" columnDivClass="col-md-6 form-group">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without your html it's hard to help you. because you code should work

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I just add the html...

Comment: @FlávioJardim Could you try with changing your $.validator.messages.required(input.labels[0].innerText)  to $.validator.messages.required(input.previousSibling.textContent) ?

Comment: @BerkÖztürk still returns "The true field is required." for all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

`input` do not have `label` property. To fetch `label` which is before `input` then you can use `input.previousElementSibling.innerText`. So your updated code would be like below.

```
$.validator.messages.required(input.previousElementSibling.innerText);
```

Alternatively if you wish to use `jquery` then you can find `text` from previous `label` with `$(input).prev('label').text()`

```
$.validator.messages.required($(input).prev('label').text());
```

Comment: $.validator.messages.required(input.labels[0].innerText) or $.validator.messages.required(input.previousElementSibling.innerText) returns exactly what I want, but the problem is on trying change the jquery required message. As far i konw on using $.validator.messages.required changes the generic message in bulk, not one by one. For generic is work fine, but i want customize it for each input, like "The Entity field is required.".

Comment: You can create runnable code in your questions, Can you please add necessary scripts.